# Missing Partial for render in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create partial which calling _topics_list.form.html.erb and have some code

```
<table class="list" cellspaceing="0">
  <thead class="head_list">
  <tr>
    <th class="column">Name</th>
    <th class="column">Description</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <tr class="row">
      <td data-label="Name" class="column first"><%= topic.name %></td>
      <td data-label="Description" class="column column_problem">
        <%= link_to topic.description, topic_path(topic), class:"link_for_column_problem" %>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Date" class="column"><%= topic.created_at.strftime("%d %b, %Y") %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Also I connect this partial with my index-file by `<%= render 'topics_list'%>`
When I try it I have error

```
Missing partial topics/_topics_list, application/_topics_list with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/dse/BlackListV2/app/views"
  * "/home/dse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activeadmin-2.6.1/app/views"
  * "/home/dse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.2.0/app/views"
  * "/home/dse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/app/views"
  * "/home/dse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.2.1/app/views"
  * "/home/dse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.2.1/app/views"
```

UPDATE

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1 class="request_headline">All Topics</h1>
<%= render 'topics_list'%>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', topic %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_topic_path(topic) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', topic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Topic', new_topic_path %>
```

Code where I render partial

Comment: can you share code from where you are trying to render `topics/_topics_list`

Comment: Yes,sure, updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partial name is `_topics_list.form.html.erb`. To render this, you need to call `render 'topics_list.form'`, not `render 'topics_list'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1 class="request_headline">All Topics</h1>
<%= render 'topics_list'%>
```

to

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1 class="request_headline">All Topics</h1>
<%= render 'topics/topics_list' %>
```

Also, a good idea will be to always pass local variables to partials instead of using global variables, that way you have an absolute control over values in partials.
`<%= render 'topics/topics_list', topics: @topics %>`

and then in partial use

```
<table class="list" cellspaceing="0">
  <thead class="head_list">
  <tr>
    <th class="column">Name</th>
    <th class="column">Description</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <% topics.each do |topic| %>
    <tr class="row">
      .....
      .....
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```